# How to access a node's menu link title in Views?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I'm surprised to not be able to find anything about this seemingly simple or routine request.

Suppose I have nodes that have long titles. They have menu items created the usual way, with short form titles.

I want to make a view of nodes that uses the menu item title of the nodes instead of the full title. However:

- There are no fields I can see that relate to the menu item,
- I can't see any available relationships that would access the menu item and make it available.

As a workaround I'm creating a custom field "subtitle" specifically for the views titles, but it's a bad workaround. Is there no way for Views to see the menu item of a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, there isn't a way.

The only thing that may possibly help you is the

#### [Menu Node Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_node_views)

> The Menu Node Views module provides Views integration for nodes
> assigned to the menu system. This module is in alpha development.

Else, a workaround is the only way.

Comment: Ahh... Drupal, where probably the biggest, most complex and most worked-on module simply doesn't talk to one of the main core parts of the system... I know many people never use the core menu system at all and simply generate menus in views, but it'd be nice to have the choice!